# helper functions are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

```
users_controller.rb

    class UsersController < ApplicationController

    include UsersHelper

      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      def create
        if isUsernameTaken?
            render 'new'
        elsif isEmailTaken?
            render 'new'
        else
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save
            else
                render 'new'
            end
         end
      end

      private

      def user_params   
         params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
     end
  end
```

---

```
users_helper.rb

module UsersHelper

    def isUsernameTaken?
        !(User.find_by(username: params[:username]).nil?)
    end

    def isEmailTaken?
        !(User.find_by(email: params[:email]).nil?)
    end


end
```

The problem is `isUsernameTaken?` or `isEmailTaken?` never gets executed and always the `else` part gets executed even if I give same username again. Why is this happening?

Comment: It is executed, otherwise you would receive noMethod error. It is just doing exactly what you told it to do rather than what you would like it to. :)

Comment: Unrelated, but your find would probably be better expressed as `User.find_by_username(params[:username]).present?` etc.

Comment: @BroiSatse: If if or elsif gets exectued how come else is also getting executed?

Comment: @InQusitive Do a simple test in the REPL: what does a `find_by` return when nothing is found? When something is found? Is it `nil`?

Comment: @InQusitive - you are not executing your helper methods in the blocks, they both return false so the else bit is executed.

Comment: You may want to read [Ruby community style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) before it's too late. Also, what you're doing seems like a better fit for traditional validations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `params[:username]` and `params[:email]` are always blank in your controller. They should be `params[:user][:username]` or `user_params[:username]`.

Anyway, those kind of checks belongs to the model, not the controller and there already are validators to do exactly what you want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :username, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: in this case if username is repeated, what output does it give so that we can refer it in view to print error message?

Comment: As for all validations, error messages will be available via `@user.errors`.